# DeterministicAead one key but change initialization vector?

Tags: encryption, tink

I'm using [Googles Tink](https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/docs/JAVA-HOWTO.md#deterministic-symmetric-key-encryption) `DeterministicAead`. What I'd like to achieve, is to use the same key over a long time, but change the ciphertext for a certain plaintext every 24 hours (for GDPR reasons).

Can I pick a new initialization vector somehow once every 24 hours? The code I'm using is:

```
KeysetHandle keysetHandle = KeysetHandle.generateNew(
                DeterministicAeadKeyTemplates.AES256_SIV);
DeterministicAead daead = keysetHandle.getPrimitive(DeterministicAead.class);
byte[] ciphertext = daead.encryptDeterministically(clearText.getBytes(), "".getBytes());
```

`ciphertext` is indeed deterministic, so at least that part is good :-)

I want to be able to decrypt the cyphertext in BigQuery, so custom primitives worry me a bit.

Note: this is not about financial data or such, it is about being able to update recommendation models on the behavior of the ciphertext while at the same time complying with privacy requirements for the user.

Answer (score 1):

By definition (from what I'm reading in those docs) there doesn't seem to be a way to specify an IV (as then it wouldn't be deterministic).

The `DeterministicAead` primitive seems to be AES with a MAC, without IV.

So, I think the only option here would be to rotate the key, or, add your own prepended/appended salt to the plaintext prior to encryption and store it for decryption.

Remember deterministic schemes aren't semantically secure.

Comment: I think you're right. The good thing is that I can just add the daily changing salt next to the ciphertext (in a stream). This way I can keep the same key for the lifetime of the plaintext item, in a separate area. The absence of semantic security is a requirement in this case. We want to update recommendation models based on anonymized user behavior. We don't use hashing because in case the customer has given permission for personalized recommendations, we can then decrypt actions over multiple days.

Comment: yup, makes sense, agreed @bartvandeenen

Comment: @bartvandeenen that sounds like a good strategy. Instead of a salt, you can also use the Unix timestamp at 00:00 each day.